# Connection problem of the python kernel with Jupyter (in Rstudio Workbench)

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab, rstudio-server

I am trying to implement JupyterLab and Jupyter Notebook in my Rstudio Workbench environment.
When starting the jupyter session I can access Jupyter.

[image: session activate]

However, when I try to run python code, nothing starts because it seems that the kernel does not connect:

[image: kernel connecting]
[image: kernel disconnected]

I don't understand because in the kernel choice, the version 3.9.5 of pyhton is proposed:

[image: kernel proposals]

Moreover in the console I get this error :

[image: consol error]

Here is a part of my Dockerfile :

```
# Install Python --------------------------------------------------------------#

ENV PYTHON_VERSION=3.9.5

RUN curl -O https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda${MINICONDA_VERSION}-Linux-x86_64.sh && \
    bash Miniconda${MINICONDA_VERSION}-Linux-x86_64.sh -bp /opt/python/${PYTHON_VERSION} && \
    /opt/python/${PYTHON_VERSION}/bin/conda install -y python==${PYTHON_VERSION} && \
    rm -rf Miniconda3-*-Linux-x86_64.sh

ENV JUPYTER_VERSION=3.8.10
RUN curl -O https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh && \
    bash Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -bp /opt/python/jupyter && \
    /opt/python/jupyter/bin/conda install -y python==${JUPYTER_VERSION} && \
    rm -rf Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh && \
    /opt/python/jupyter/bin/pip install \
    jupyter==1.0.0 \
    'jupyterlab<3.0.0' \
    rsp_jupyter \
    rsconnect_jupyter && \
    /opt/python/jupyter/bin/jupyter kernelspec remove python3 -f && \
    /opt/python/jupyter/bin/pip uninstall -y ipykernel

ENV PATH="/opt/python/${PYTHON_VERSION}/bin:${PATH}"

RUN /opt/python/"${PYTHON_VERSION}"/bin/pip install --upgrade \
    pip setuptools wheel

RUN /opt/python/${PYTHON_VERSION}/bin/pip install ipykernel
RUN /opt/python/${PYTHON_VERSION}/bin/python -m ipykernel install --name py${PYTHON_VERSION} --display-name "Python ${PYTHON_VERSION}"

# Install Jupyter Notebook and RSW/RSC Notebook Extensions and Packages -------#

RUN /opt/python/${PYTHON_VERSION}/bin/pip install jupyter jupyterlab rsp_jupyter rsconnect_jupyter

RUN /opt/python/${PYTHON_VERSION}/bin/jupyter-nbextension install --sys-prefix --py rsp_jupyter && \
     /opt/python/${PYTHON_VERSION}/bin/jupyter-nbextension enable --sys-prefix --py rsp_jupyter && \
     /opt/python/${PYTHON_VERSION}/bin/jupyter-nbextension install --sys-prefix --py rsconnect_jupyter && \
     /opt/python/${PYTHON_VERSION}/bin/jupyter-nbextension enable --sys-prefix --py rsconnect_jupyter && \
     /opt/python/${PYTHON_VERSION}/bin/jupyter-serverextension enable --sys-prefix --py rsconnect_jupyter
```

And here is a part of workbench.sh file :

```
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# ---- launcher-mounts
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
cat > /etc/rstudio/launcher-mounts << EOF
# Required home directory mount for RSP, Launcher, and Kubernetes
MountType: NFS
Host: ${nfs_host_ip}
Path: ${user_workspace_path}/{USER}
MountPath: /home/{USER}
ReadOnly: false
Cluster: Kubernetes
EOF

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# ---- jupyter.conf
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
cat > /etc/rstudio/jupyter.conf << EOF
jupyter-exe=/opt/python/3.9.5/bin/jupyter
labs-enabled=1
notebooks-enabled=1
session-cull-minutes=240
default-session-cluster=Kubernetes
default-session-container-image=${r_session_container_nightly}
EOF
```

Can you help me to fix this kernel problem please?